# mongoDB replication with offline nodes

Tags: mongodb

Is it possible to set up mongoDB replica set with following scenario (if it is,how):

- 2 servers always online running mongodb, one of them holds the main node, the other one a rescue copy;
- n computers each of them running mongodb, occasionally connected to internet, holding nodes which need synchronizing with main node, when they go online.

Comment: Are you considering another database options? If so, you may check CouchDB, which has a great offline replication.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Backup only. In order to do this, you'll have to specify the `priority` of this node to `0`. If your node is never going to be used as master nor queried, you can also set `buildIndexes` to `false`.
  More informations [here](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Replica+Set+Configuration#ReplicaSetConfiguration-Memberoptions).
- Intermitent slave. Due to limitations (mainly on the `oplog` queue), you can't have a slave halted for a very long time if you have many writes on your MongoDB, see [here](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Resyncing+a+Very+Stale+Replica+Set+Member). However, you can use the `mongodump` and `mongorestore` tools directly over network or by script + sync the backup file. More informations [here](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Import+Export+Tools#ImportExportTools-mongodumpandmongorestore). Note that a restore will bring a db or collection in a server and recreate the indexes completely (if you restore the system.indexes collection too) which can take some time.

Comment: After I read the docs from your links, => what I really want is sort of multi_master conf, which is not possible due the replication philosophy of mongoDB. So dump/restore are my friends. Thanks. +1